# SPARQL Queries with Fuseki Server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, sparql, ubuntu-18.04, fuseki

I'm trying to run SPARQL queries with [Fuseki Server](https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi) on Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to start the server in the terminal with `./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds`, I get the following errors.

I've seen some similar questions and I assume it has something to do with compatibility issues with Java 11. I've installed Java 8, and I still get the same errors. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

```
    WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2020-06-18 11:44:21,839 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-18 11:44:21,956 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:21,957 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-18 11:44:21,958 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:21,959 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-18 11:44:21,965 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:21,965 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-18 11:44:21,968 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:21,977 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-18 11:44:21,979 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:21,980 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-18 11:44:21,988 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,072 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,073 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,074 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,074 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,075 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,076 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,077 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,079 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,080 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,082 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,090 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,091 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,559 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Loggers
2020-06-18 11:44:22,564 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Appenders
2020-06-18 11:44:22,564 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ThresholdFilter
2020-06-18 11:44:22,571 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,572 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,580 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,583 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,584 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,588 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,589 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,595 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,596 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,596 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,609 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,609 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for AppenderRef
2020-06-18 11:44:22,610 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,610 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,611 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-18 11:44:22,611 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for AppenderRef
2020-06-18 11:44:22,612 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Root
2020-06-18 11:44:22,615 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Loggers
2020-06-18 11:44:22,616 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for PatternLayout
2020-06-18 11:44:22,616 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Console
2020-06-18 11:44:22,616 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for PatternLayout
2020-06-18 11:44:22,617 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Console
2020-06-18 11:44:22,617 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Appenders
2020-06-18 11:44:22,618 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for ThresholdFilter
2020-06-18 11:44:22,619 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,622 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,627 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,630 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,635 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,636 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,641 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,642 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,642 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,642 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-18 11:44:22,643 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-18 11:44:22,643 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

Comment: *"I've installed Java 8, and I still get the same errors"* - but does this mean you also set Java 8 as current Java version? What does `java --version` say?

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1900), a quick fix is here: https://gist.github.com/afs/a862c0e71b37ce617cd0a592b60609f1 - just run the Bash script to download fixed version of Fuseki

Comment: @UninformedUser The quick fix works, thanks. `java --version`  gives `Unrecognized option: --version Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.` Although, it shows 8 when I change it to `java -version`.  `java --version` and `java -version` works when it's changed to 11.

Comment: yeah, my bad, it's `java -version`