# Unable to start jena fuseki with Apache Tomcat or as standalone server

Tags: tomcat, jena, fuseki

I have been trying to open a fuseki session following the following tutorial: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-quick-start.html

I downloaded the package, unzipped and placed the WAR file in the web app directory as indicated. Then I started the tomcat server (catalina start). The tomcat server is correctly accessible at http://localhost:8080.
However I get an error 404 when I go to http://localhost:8080/fuseki on my browser. The 404 error report looks like that:

*Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/fuseki] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.*

Alternatively, I have also tried running the fuseki-server script directly in command line as follows:
./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds

but this gives me the following list of errors:

```
./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,607 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,670 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,672 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,673 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,673 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,674 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,674 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,675 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,676 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,676 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,677 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,678 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,700 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,700 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,701 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,701 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,702 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,702 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,702 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,703 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,703 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,704 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,705 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,705 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,885 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Loggers
2020-06-20 20:06:22,886 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Appenders
2020-06-20 20:06:22,887 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ThresholdFilter
2020-06-20 20:06:22,891 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,891 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,892 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,892 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,893 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,893 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for AppenderRef
2020-06-20 20:06:22,894 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,894 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,895 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,895 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-20 20:06:22,895 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for AppenderRef
2020-06-20 20:06:22,896 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Root
2020-06-20 20:06:22,896 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Loggers
2020-06-20 20:06:22,897 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for PatternLayout
2020-06-20 20:06:22,897 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Console
2020-06-20 20:06:22,897 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for PatternLayout
2020-06-20 20:06:22,898 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Console
2020-06-20 20:06:22,898 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Appenders
2020-06-20 20:06:22,899 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for ThresholdFilter
2020-06-20 20:06:22,899 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,900 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,900 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,900 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,901 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,901 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,902 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,902 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,903 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,903 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-20 20:06:22,904 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-20 20:06:22,904 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

My configuration is as follows:

macOS high sierra version 10.13.6

java version:
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Fuseki version: 3.15.0

I tried to reinstall fuseki using homebrew and still got the same errors. I also tried to set the FUSEKI_HOME variable to the directory where fuseki is installed but this did not solve the issue.

I am new to jena and tomcat and I tried several installation methods, so may be I did something wrong in the configuration or may be I am missing something ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Two separate issues: running the standalone server@: see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446300/sparql-queries-with-fuseki-server-on-ubuntu-18-04 - it's a bug in 3.15.0 , either run 3.14.0 or apply the fix described there.

Comment: For running in Tomcat: Does the war file have the right permissions for Tomcat? Has it been unpack in the webapps directory? Also, if this is Tomcat9, there are some sandbox restrictions that may be involved: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r063159137c6ef2ba51d046555cd1732ba863aacf5b1d7370a0ea1be5%40%3Cusers.jena.apache.org%3E

Comment: Thanks! It works with 3.14.0. Regarding Tomcat I haven't tried yet your suggestions.