# How to get Jena Fuseki running in a cygwin bash shell?

Tags: windows, cygwin, sparql, jena, fuseki

I am currently running Amazon Corretto Java 11.0.
I have downloaded the apache-jena-fuseki-3.15.0.zip.  The archive has been extracted.  From a cygwin bash shell, I ran:

```
fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

The server is accessible from a browser at localhost:3030.  However, the startup dumped a lot of errors.

Documentation for installing and running on Windows is sparse.  I am trying to get to a point where I can upload my ontology and execute SPARQL queries.  I can do neither at this point.  Any ideas of what might be wrong?  Any pointers to online installation guides or videos?

Here are the errors:

```
2020-06-21 22:55:45,545 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,558 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,559 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,559 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,559 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,560 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,560 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,560 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,561 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,561 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,561 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,562 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,572 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,573 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,573 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,573 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,574 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,574 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,574 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,575 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,575 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,575 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,575 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,575 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,630 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Loggers
2020-06-21 22:55:45,630 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Appenders
2020-06-21 22:55:45,631 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for ThresholdFilter
2020-06-21 22:55:45,633 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,633 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,634 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,634 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,635 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,635 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,635 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,636 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,636 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,636 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,637 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,637 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for AppenderRef
2020-06-21 22:55:45,637 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,637 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,638 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Logger
2020-06-21 22:55:45,638 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for AppenderRef
2020-06-21 22:55:45,639 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Root
2020-06-21 22:55:45,639 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Loggers
2020-06-21 22:55:45,640 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for PatternLayout
2020-06-21 22:55:45,640 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Console
2020-06-21 22:55:45,640 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for PatternLayout
2020-06-21 22:55:45,640 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Console
2020-06-21 22:55:45,641 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Appenders
2020-06-21 22:55:45,641 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for ThresholdFilter
2020-06-21 22:55:45,642 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [d]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,642 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,643 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,643 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,644 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [level]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,644 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,645 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,645 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,645 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,646 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
2020-06-21 22:55:45,646 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [n]
2020-06-21 22:55:45,647 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

Comment: It's a known problem with 3.15.0 Either use v 3.14.0. por the fix mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446300/sparql-queries-with-fuseki-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Put your comment in the answer section so that I can give it due credit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the Apache Jena Fuseki v3.15.0 combined jar (`fuseki-server.jar`, not the war file packaging, nor the non-UI `jena-fuseki-server` form). It is a bug in v 3.15.0 only, not in 3.14.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1900

An in-place fix:

https://gist.github.com/afs/a862c0e71b37ce617cd0a592b60609f1

This bash script downloads jena-fuseki-server-3.15.0.jar which does not have the same problem, extracts the "Log4j2Plugins.dat", then replaces the file in fuseki-server.jar.

An alternative to consider is using jena-fuseki-server as a service.  It does not have a UI nor maintain a "run/" area - instead it uses a command line arguments, including a configuration file argument, each time it is started.

Comment: The 3.14.0 Apache Jena Fuseki server is located at http://archive.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/. The runtime messages are nominal.  SPARQL is embedded in the install and runs fine.